# Compiling with a multi-precision math library in C using Code::Blocks on Windows

Tags: c, codeblocks, pari

I'm having a lot of trouble figuring out how to do this. I need an arbitrary precision library for math in C. I'm good with either CLN or PARI/GP, both of which I've installed. I'm using Windows, so I had to do this via Cygwin, and ran the ./Configure files, followed by make install.

Everything's built, but I cannot figure out how to link it all and use it. I'm using Code::Blocks, and anytime I try to include the necessary header files, there are loads of errors. I also link the .a file with the library, but no help either. The header files create far too many errors.

Could anyone give me a run through on how I can make this work?

Comment: errors (for example, for CLN) include not being able to find other header files tied to the header I try to include, as well as "expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'cln'" repeated several times.

Comment: You need to let the compiler know where to find the header files for compilation; and the code for linking. Check out [this page for CLN](http://www.ginac.de/CLN/cln_11.html) or try `gcc \`pkg-config --cflags cln\` prog.cc \`pkg-config --libs cln\``

Comment: See also [SO 4175451](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4175451/using-pari-library-for-c) by the same poster.

Comment: I've got everything linked, but I still get errors inside of the header files, such as four "expected ')' before numeric constant" inside of paridecl.h for PARI, when I try to build.